# Displaying phone format XAML/c#

Tags: c#, regex, xaml, phone-number

In my windows phone project, I would like the user to enter his phone number in xxx-xxx-xxxx format. The country code it not required. I tried to implement regex, but i am not getting it right. I just want it to be displayed to the user **as he enters it**, nothing more, nothing less. This is what I have used

```
^\(\d{3}\) ?\d{3}( |-)?\d{4}$
```

But no matter what i put in, I always get this error (in this case 5) *"Unrecognized escape sequence"*. I noticed, this is only with reference to the oblique. When I add a *""* after it, the error goes away, but I do not get what I want. Is there a special way to input numbers in the textbox in than manner, on the XAML level?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: define your pattern as verbatim string. `@"^\(\d{3}\) ?\d{3}( |-)?\d{4}$"`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the "Unrecognized escape sequence" error. Can you also help me with getting the pattern right? The one I have isn't wokring for some reason. It does not take the number in xxx-xxx-xxxx format, but only in xxxxxxxxxx. Thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your regex inside verbatim string and also put the space, hyphen inside a group and make it as optional.

```
@"^\(\d{3}\)([- ]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uV8qU5/3)

Answer (score 0):

For testing your `RegEx` you can use this site: http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1.

For your xxx-xxx-xxxx format I would use it:`^\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$`